# Access control section on Advanced Settings

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

I would like to give a user the ability to change the following properties on a Survey.

- SPList.WriteSecurity
- SPList.ReadSecurity

Normally there is a section under Advanced Settings (`/_layouts/15/advsetng.aspx`) for this. It shows the options for *Read access* and *Create and Edit access*.

Unfortunately even when the user is given the Full Control permission level on the Survey, the relevant section is missing for them from the Advanced Settings.

I can only make the relevant section of the page appear by making the user a Site Collection Administrator and I cannot do this.

What governs whether this Access Control section appears?

Answer (score 1):

The survey was not inheriting permissions from its parent site so I assumed all relevant permissions were between the user and the survey.

However, in order for the user to see the *Read access* and *Create and Edit access*, the user must have certain permissions on the *parent site* as well. The minimum permissions I am able to use are:

- Override List Behaviors (this is the important one)
- View Items
- View Pages
- Open

NB the same behaviour is observed for a Discussion Forum.